Black screen pulses after turning on HDR in Settings
I have been experiencing a problem with the display becomes disconnected periodically, and it renders the computer completely unusable.
I won't disclose the exact nature of the problem, but I have found a perfectly simple way to reproduce the problem without fail.
If I open the Windows 11 UWP Settings app, go to System tab and click Display, there is a toggle with text "Use HDR". If I use that toggle to switch on HDR in the operating system, then the problem immediately recurs, every 5 seconds or so, the screen would turn black with thin green lines forming a slanted stripe, then the screen would immediately turn completely black for a few seconds.
Then the screen would appear to be working, except the colors are dimmer, white becomes dusty yellow, and after a few seconds the glitching image would be shown for a split second then the screen becomes completely black for a few more seconds, this repeats ad infinitum until HDR is turned off in the Settings.
My monitor is Foundstar FD250VS which is HDR capable, and the monitor has a separate HDR switch unrelated to the OS, it is working properly and turning it on makes everything brighter as opposed to the OS' HDR making everything darker, and I always leave the monitor HDR on.
The OS is Windows 11 Pro 23H2, kept up to date by Windows Update, installed this week, no system file corruption whatsoever, the GPU is NVIDIA Geforce GTX 1050 Ti and I downloaded 551.86-desktop-win10-win11-64bit-international-dch-whql.exe from official NVIDIA website to install graphics driver right after I have installed the OS, and I used Snappy Driver Installer to install drivers for everything else, so it is extremely unlikely to be a driver issue. I have also tested that the key combo Ctrl +  + Shift + B restarts the GPU while the problem occurs, as indicated by the beep sound, but it doesn't help.
This problem has rendered certain programs completely unusable and require extensive workarounds to make them work. What causes this problem?

Normally you need to both enable HDR on the monitor AND in software (in the game or OS). Having HDR enabled will completely change the dynamic range, so it is logical that enabling HDR without support will make it darker, and turning HDR on the monitor on without software support, will make things brighter. The display glitch may also happen because you are forcing a larger range of light values than the monitor can handle and the other way around. The question is, if you have HDR enabled on both ends, does the glitch go away?

@LPChip Of course I had tested it, I have checked and confirmed that the problem is directly correlated to the OS HDR settings. The glitch only occurs when the OS HDR is enabled, and it occurs both when monitor HDR is on and off, the monitor's HDR settings don't affect the glitch at all.
